# Why does Microsoft Word ctrl-F take over 20 seconds to open its Nav.. window, the first time?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

If no Word instances and I open a word doc, it opens fast enough,
but then ctrl-F takes ~20 seconds before Navigation window opens.

After that, no more delay.  if I close nav, then press ctrl-F opens in a split second.

The problem occurs with all my Word .docx files.
The problem occurs 100 miles away at the company office, with ~300Mbps Internet access.

No 3rd part malware software running.

I'm using OFFICE 365 on a very fast, multi-core Windows 10 newer laptop.
Internet is 20Mbps up and down.

UPDATE
Once I have done ctrl-f and opened Nav once, and closed it, it is instantaneous to open again.  BUT, if I close all instances of Word and open it again, ctrl-F will again take half a minute.

And, if I do anything after ctrl-f and while waiting for it to open, then I get this:

[image]

Comment: Can't tell you the why. On my system it is virtually instantaneous. Does this happen with you if you start Word in safe mode? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72

Comment: Yeah, it's probably some add-on that tries to contact homebase on Mars before it answers. Try safe mode, and if this is fast, disable them one-by-one until you find the bad one.

Comment: Nobody can accurately answer that question unless they are a software engineer working on the Microsoft Office for Windows project team. All other comments from others are opinions and quesses.

Comment: @RichMichaels Are you suggesting that Doug should not try safe mode?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-does-word-ctrl-f-take-12-a-minute-to-open/271da779-81fc-483c-b84f-b5ec5bf4fa86